# Why implementing swap() as non-throwing

Tags: c++, c++03

I do understand why sometimes it is recommended to implement our own `swap()` function for a given class.

For instance, if we have a class following the *pimpl* idiom we would likely want to define our own *copy constructor*, so that it performs a *deep copy* of the contents of the object passed as an argument instead of the *shallow copy* that would be performed by the *default copy constructor*. The same could apply to the *copy assignment operator*.

Since it seems that `std::swap()` is implemented in terms of (at least, when it comes to C++03) both the *copy constructor* and the *copy assignment operator*. It would be inefficient to perform deep copies of the objects to be swapped, since just a swap of the pointers contained by these objects need to be done.

My question is **why** we should implement our `swap()` function as a ***non-throwing*** one.

In the case explained above, I assume it is just about semantics: since no new resources are being allocated (i.e.: two existing pointers are just being swapped). It wouldn't make much sense for such a kind of function to throw an exception.

However, there may be other reasons or scenarios I am overlooking in this reasoning.

Comment: Counterquestion: why should we implement a throwing function if it is not necessary? Exceptions must be handled. You must decide what to do, and protect the code with try-catch whenever you call that function. That's some work. If there's a way to avoid it entirely, why not?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by **non-throwing**? Do you mean `throw()`? 2. Before asking *why* swap should be non-throwing, how about first asking: *should* swap be non-throwing?

Comment: When would swap throw?

Comment: I actually mean, that the function **never throws**. Not `throw()` as part of the function's signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some classes such as

> a class following the pimpl idiom

we know that the implementation of `swap` will not need to throw because

> It wouldn't make much sense for such a kind of function to throw an exception.

When it doesn't make sense to throw an exception, then it is best not to throw an exception.

---

There can be other classes such as those that contain complex members without a specialized swap function, but with potentially throwing copy constructor / assignment. For such classes we can not implement swap that never throws.

Comment: So, implementing our own `swap()` function is not only about performance, but also *exception-safety*, i.e.: moving from a `swap()` function that may throw to one that will not. The non-specialized version of `std::swap()` may throw because resources may be allocated.

Comment: @Neroku a very keen observation.

Comment: The non-specialized version of `swap()` is unlikely to throw now it uses move-construction and move-assignment, if they exist.

Comment: @Useless *now* meaning *since C++11* to be exact.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is **why** we should implement our `swap()` function as a ***non-throwing*** one

1. Because `swap` is completely useless if it might throw.

   Consider: you `swap` two instances, and the operation throws. Now, what state are they in?

   The strong guarantee is that there are no side-effects if an exception was thrown, meaning both original objects are left in their original state.

   If we *can't* meet the strong guarantee, we simply can't use `swap` in many cases, because there's no way to recover usefully from a failure, and there's no point in writing that version of `swap` at all.
2. Because there's no reason for it to throw.

   The trivial implementation of `swap` (now) uses move-assignment and -construction.

   There's generally no reason for a move-constructor to throw: it doesn't allocate anything new, it's just re-seating existing data. There's generally no reason for move-assignment to throw (as above), and destructors should never throw - and those are the only operations required.

Comment: And following from the first point, if type A has a potentially-throwing swap, it makes composition difficult. If type B has two A members then `B::swap(B&)` can't be safely swapped, because either A could throw and leave the B in an unknown and unrecoverable state.

Comment: Regarding the first point. What if the *copy constructor* might throw but not so the *copy assignment operator*? In this case `swap()` might throw, but the *strong guarantee* is not lost.

Comment: Not true - you could have finished swapping the first of B's two A members successfully, and then throw on the second. In that case, your B objects are in a possibly-unusable state. You should be using the _move_ variants now anyway, and there's rarely a good reason for them to throw.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

I've originally understood the question as "why would you use the `throw` specifier on the `swap` function. This answer might be off topic since I doesn't explain why would `swap` never throw.

---

I think the best answer is **why not ?**.

Why would you not specify that a function will never throw when this function as no reason to throw ?

You should always implement function as non-throwing when they have no reason to throw exception: you offer stronger guaranty for your function.

Furthermore, with some meta programming, you can take advantages of functions being non-throwing. Some STL classes use that to have faster member function when the swap/copy/move(C++11) is no-throw. (Actually I'm not sure that they take advantage of a function being no-throw in pre-C++11 code)

Answer (score 1):

`swap`ing your pImpls [can't fail](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/swap2), in a well-formed program. (And the behaviour in an ill formed program *doesn't matter*). There is nothing to throw